# Does anyone have the Hallman Article about the P-star analysis from 1989

Tags: inflation, forecasting

I'm currently studying the P-star Analysis for the prediction of inflation. I want to read some articles about it and i found some on Jstor, especially the Hallman-Porter-Small article (1991). But in the latter, it is written that a previous article (about the P-star) wrote by Hallman (1989) exists but i can't find it.
Does anyone know where I could get it ?
Thanks

Comment: maybe [here](https://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/fedred75&id=537&collection=journals&index=)